# How can I listen to onclick event SpotLight Helper and attach the TransformControls to the light?

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouseevent

## The problem:

When I click on the cube, TransformControls is attached on the cube. But when I click on the light helper, nothing happen. I want the TransformControls to be attached on the light when I click the light helper. Can you help me with this?

This is the most minimal example.

http://codepen.io/kranzy/pen/ALOYZw

or if you need code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 ); 
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ); 
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement ); 
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ); 
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } ); 
var transformControls = new THREE.TransformControls(camera,renderer.domElement); 
scene.add(transformControls); 
var objects = []; 
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ); 
cube.position.x = -10; 
scene.add( cube ); 
objects.push(cube); 
var light = new THREE.SpotLight(); 
scene.add(light); 
var help = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(light); 
scene.add(help); 
objects.push(help); 
camera.position.z = 5; 
var render = function () { 
    requestAnimationFrame( render ); 
    cube.rotation.x += 0.1; 
    cube.rotation.y += 0.1; 
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 
}; 
render(); 
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false ); 
function onWindowResize(){ 
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight; 
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); 
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
} 
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false ); 
document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false ); 
function onDocumentTouchStart(event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    event.clientX = event.touches[0].clientX; 
    event.clientY = event.touches[0].clientY; 
    onDocumentMouseDown(event); 
} 
function onDocumentMouseDown(event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    mouse = new THREE.Vector2(); 
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1; 
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1; 
    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); 
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera); 
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects); 
    if(intersects.length > 0){ 
        SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object; 
        console.log(SELECTED); 
        if (SELECTED.constructor === THREE.SpotLightHelper) { 
            transformControls.attach(SELECTED.light); 
        } else { 
            transformControls.attach(SELECTED); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: OK?  Every time you comment I get notification stop commenting if not necessary please

Comment: You cannot click on a light helper. It doesn't have a mesh so it will not intersect with ray casts. Am I missing something?

Comment: but why @ http://threejs.org/editor i can click on light helper easily? it is so hard. lost 4 rep because downvote and now i give you 50 rep. can you try more?

Comment: @GökhanKurt now it's time to check this out again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is raycaster.
Add the second parameter of raycaster.intersectObjects() to true.

So the final code is
`var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);`

Here is the working sample for attach the transformControls to the light: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGJxBj

I hope this should helps you..

Comment: thank you very much! because i am just 13 years old i don't know that second parameter. now i raycast 2 times: 1st time with 2nd param true to detect light helper, 2nd time with 2nd param false to detect other things. it will result in duplicate code but it works. i am not working for a team anyway.